# How do i cluster these data?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

So basically, I have this data:

```
    User_ID   Product_ID   Gender      Age     Occupation   City_Category
1   1000001   P00069042      F        0-17        10            A
2   1000001   P00248942      F        0-17        10            A
3   1000001   P00087842      F        0-17        10            A

    Stay_In_Current_City_Years  Marital_Status  Product_Category_1
                2                       0                 3 
                2                       0                 1 
                2                       0                 12
    Product_Category_2 Product_Category_3 Purchase
             0                 0            8370
             6                 14           15200
             0                 0            1422
```

What is the best features that i can take to perform kmeans on this data set?

The kmeans should help identify the different clusters of consumers within the data.

This is the correlation that i currently have for this:
[Correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Ps5.png)

For this kmeans, do you think that it is a good idea to kmeans:

1. Occupation with Purchase
2. Stay_In_Current_City_years with Purchase
3. Purchase & Product_Category_3

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question.

The question must *not* be "what can I hack to make k-means run somehow on this data".

Instead the question you ought to be asking is: what mathematical properties would a meaningful clustering of this data have, and what algorithm can I extend to find a good solution of that equation.

Because your task is not to randomly partition the data, but to find good partitions. So you need to first define "good".